# Multiple line UIlabel in UItableviewcell using Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have set `setMaXPreferredLayoutWidth` to `UILabel` and added all the required constraints to the `UIlabel` now I can see multiline `UIlabel` in my `UItableviewcell` but my problem is I am getting extra padding at the top and bottom of my `UIlabel` based on `MaxpreferredLayoutWidth` value.

When I set the `MaxPreferreLayoutWidth` to 200 I get this
[image: If maxPreferredLayoutwidth set to 200]

When I set the `MaxPreferreLayoutWidth` to 100 I get this

[image: MaxpreferredLayoutWidth = 100]

In general `UIlabel` height depends based on `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.
Can any one say me how to remove this extra padding and render the exact height of `UIlabel`?

Comment: Just to make things more clear I am using Autolayout in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to set the tableviewcell's frame while calculating the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
Ex:

```
[tableViewCell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(tableViewCell.bounds))];
```

and then in `layoutSubviews` method of `UItableviewcell` we have to set the `preferredMaxLayoutwidth`
Ex:

```
[self.multilineLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
CGSize suggestedSize = [textWithMultipleLines sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];//here "width" is the maximum acceptable width of myLabel
CGRect labelFrame = myLabel.frame;
labelFrame.size = suggestedSize;
[myLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
```

and in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
{
     //get the string assigned to label
     CGSize suggestedSize = [stringAssignedToLabel sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
     return suggestedSize.height+5;
}
```

Comment: I am using Autolayout in my code.. But in your code snipper you are asking me to setFrame.Is there a way to solve it using Autolayout ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to this is to extend your own UITableViewCell class, and create a UILabel there, also create a public getMethod:

> Interface:

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight;
```

> Implementation:

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight {
  return label.frame.size.height
}
```

> TableView File:

```
-(CGFloat)heightForRowAtIndexPath {
    return [cell getLabelHeight]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {

   your_cell_instance = [[Your_Cell_Class alloc]initWithTableViewCellStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault andReuseID:your_reuse_id];

   your_cell_instance.text = @"Your Long Text"
   [your_cell_instance setNumberOfLines:0];
   [your_cell_instance sizeToFit];

   return your_cell_instance;

}
```

**Its important to set first the text of the label and then // number of lines and sizeToFit //**

**And you need to reload the tableView data in proper of your time**

*I Haven't time to test it, but i hope it works.*

Comment: I am using Autolayout in my code and for some reasons I cant disable autolayout in my code.Is there a way to solve it with  Autolayout enabled ?